# Converting CSV to DBF using ArcPy giving ERROR 000732

Tags: arcpy, convert, csv, error-000732, dbf

My code

```
import arcpy, os, shutil, re
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = "R:\GIS_Data\Earthquake_Data\Updates\Eq_updates.mdb"
path = r"R:\GIS_Data\Earthquake_Data\Updates"
In_path = r"R:\GIS_Data\Earthquake_Data\Updates\OGS_Auto_Updates\csv"
Out_path = r"R:\GIS_Data\Earthquake_Data\Updates\OGS_Auto_Updates\dbf_new"
#gdb_name = r"R:\GIS_Data\Earthquake_Data\Updates\Eq_updates.mdb"
connect = "\\"

# convert csv to dbf in a separate folder
# Local variables inputs and outputs: filenames

for filenames in os.listdir(In_path):
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(filenames, r"R:\GIS_Data\Earthquake_Data\Updates\Eq_updates.mdb", os.path.splitext(filenames)[0] + ".dbf")
    print("Successfully converted" + os.path.splitext(csv)[0] + ".csv to " + os.path.splitext(csv)[0] + ".dbf")
```

The error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2249, in TableToTable
raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset 2000-2009.csv does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (TableToTable).
```

Am I missing a import or other command?

Comment: Do the rules allowed for file names permit 1) starting with a number and 2 including a -?

Comment: Most of the files do start with a number.  I try with a letter in front.  thx

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code:

You should add a file extension check after os.listdir to make sure your only looking at .csv files:

```
for filenames in os.listdir(In_path):
    if filenames.endswith('.csv'):
        # continue on with code
```

Next, your saving a .dbf to a .mdb file which is not possible.  Change the out path to the Out_path variable.

Finally, since the env workspace is pointing to the mdb the in_table parameters needs the full file path, update the table to table statement to this:

```
# exporting to folder
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(os.path.join(In_path, filenames), Out_path, os.path.splitext(filenames)[0] + ".dbf")
```

Comment: Thanks, I added your suggestions:  1st though I had removed the csv check because that is all that is in there, but safety is always a good thing so I put it back.  2nd the conversion as you have it doesn't tell it to become a dbf.    So I tried adding + .dbf before the final ).  New Error message:  "File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2249, in TableToTable
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (TableToTable)."

Comment: I updated the code snippet to include the .dbf file extension again.  The new error suggest an invalid file character maybe a space or some other character in the .csv filename.